# A simple mysql query runs forever

Tags: mysql, database-administration

I've a table with 10,000 records `precommit_tags_change_lists`, a select query on this takes forever.

I tried to add an index as below which also hangs...

```
ALTER TABLE `precommit_tags_change_lists` ADD INDEX `change_list_id` (`change_list_id`)
```

Following is the structure of the table, any guidance on how to debug this and what could be causing this issue?

[image]

UPDATE:

Quite a  few process are stuck with state "Waiting for table metadata lock" on the table `precommit_tags_changelists`

[image]

Comment: what's the `SELECT` query?

Comment: @SamuelCook - Its `SELECT * FROM aci_dev.precommit_tags_change_lists;`

Comment: Is `SHOW PROCESSLIST` clear? Does `REPAIR TABLE` complete successfully? If you're really stuck, sometimes powering down and rebooting the MySQL instance and bringing it back up shakes out any consistency problems.

Comment: Can you append the information for this output to your question: `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM aci_dev.precommit_tags_change_lists;` ?

Comment: @Paut T - even that command stuck but I have updated my question with output of  `SELECT * FROM information_schema.processlist WHERE `STATE` LIKE '%metadata%'
order by host desc` where quite a few process are stuck with state `Waiting for table metadata lock` on the table precommit_tags_changelists how to kill these processes?